# Why down and right border of my table is invisible?

Tags: html, css

Why right and down border is invisible?

Here is my table:
http://jsfiddle.net/dFu5e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing white TD borders over the table border.

You can fix the problem by setting the table border to 2 px.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JZLtJ/)

But instead of all those border definitions, I would recommend for next time to use CSS. There are many tools helping you define the CSS of tables for your goals. For example :

- http://www.somacon.com/p141.php
- http://www.css-generators.com/css-tools/css-table-generator

Answer (score 1):

Remove tr and td border.
Use border="1" and cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0" for table tag:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
....
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can remove the `overflow: hidden` from the table.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `overflow:hidden`. [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFu5e/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from your `table` style, fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/dFu5e/7/).